# How can I search in PDF documents/PDX catalog in powershell

Tags: search, pdf, powershell, catalog

I have a vendor that supplies their documentation library as a series of PDF files (and some CHM files) and include a .PDX catalog also.

I want to write a powershell script to front end it (using either powershell forms, or hosting powershell in asp.net).

I'm in the early stages, I've worked out how to get document information from the PDF stream (the xmpmeta XML metadata block near the end of the PDF file - one of the few streams in the file that's in plaintext) which looks like this:

```
    <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.2.1-c043 52.372728, 2009/01/18-15:08:04 
       "><rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><rdf:Description rdf:about="
" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"><pdf:Producer>GPL Ghostscript 8.64</pdf:Producer><pdf:Keywo
rds>86000056-413</pdf:Keywords></rdf:Description><rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.ad
obe.com/xap/1.0/"><xmp:ModifyDate>2011-03-03T17:38:34-05:00</xmp:ModifyDate><xmp:CreateDate>2011-01-28
T23:12:07+05:30</xmp:CreateDate><xmp:CreatorTool>PScript5.dll Version 5.2</xmp:CreatorTool><xmp:Metada
taDate>2011-03-03T17:38:34-05:00</xmp:MetadataDate></rdf:Description><rdf:Description rdf:about="" xml
ns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"><xmpMM:DocumentID>6cb2263d-2d61-11e0-0000-1390d57dcfcb</xmp
MM:DocumentID><xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:1a0e68ba-14ad-4a03-b7a1-0a0e127b8753</xmpMM:InstanceID></rdf:Desc
ription><rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><dc:format>applicati
on/pdf</dc:format><dc:title><rdf:Alt><rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">I/O Subsystem Programming Guide</rdf
:li></rdf:Alt></dc:title><dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Unisys Information Development</rdf:li></rdf:Seq
></dc:creator><dc:description><rdf:Alt><rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">ClearPath MCP 13.1,Application Dev
elopment,Administration,ClearPath MCP</rdf:li></rdf:Alt></dc:description></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF><
/x:xmpmeta>
```

using the following code (powershell v3, in v2 you need to select and expand the properties thus `[string]$title = ($rdf.GetElementsByTagName('dc:title')|    Select -expand Alt|Select -expand li)."#text"`):

```
$file = ".\Downloads\68698703-007\PDF\86000056-413.pdf"

#determine what line in file the xmpmeta string starts
[int]$startln = (select-string -pattern '^<x:' $file).ToString().Split(":")[2]

#determine what line in file the xmpmeta string ends
[int]$endln = (select-string -pattern '^</x:' $file).ToString().Split(":")[2]
$startln--

#grab the xmpmeta and cast as type xml
[xml]$xmp = (gc $file)["$startln".."$endln"]
[xml]$rdf = $xmp.xmpmeta.InnerXml

#get title/creator/description element text
[string]$title = $rdf.GetElementsByTagName('dc:title').Alt.li."#text"
[string]$creator = $rdf.GetElementsByTagName('dc:creator').Alt.li."#text"
[string]$description = $rdf.GetElementsByTagName('dc:description').Alt.li."#text"
```

That's crucial because the filenames are in the format 12345678-123.pdf, the actual title is in the metadata itself, as well as document category etc.

So, I can produce a list of documents (displaying their proper titles, not the real filename) and allow them to be launched, but I also want to be able to search in all the documents using PDX file, but it's by no means plaintext!

I guess I could use one of a number of tools out there to convert each PDF into text, search it, repeat for each document and then return results for each document.

But, it strikes me that Adobe Reader already does that, so can I either start AcroRd32.exe with switches that will start the search, with search terms I've passed in to the AcroRd32 program, or can I use Adobe Search.API from within Powershell?

Any ideas specifically on automating load of the .PDX in Adobe Reader and firing off the search, or using adobe's API in powershell?

**EDIT:**
I can now launch acrobat from command line and search (so could mimic this in powershell) but the search only works when searching a PDF, not a PDX catalog. Both bring up the search pane, but only in a PDF document does the search field get populated and the search executed.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader>AcroRd32.exe /A "search=trim" "P:\Doc Library\PDF\00_home.pdx"
```

Or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader>AcroRd32.exe /A "search=trim" "P:\Doc Library\PDF\86000056-413.pdf"
```

Regards,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but be aware that the searching you do is potentially dangerous and that there is a better way to find the XMP metadata in a PDF file. XMP was designed specifically to be "findable" by text search. To that purpose it has a well defined begin and end code defined that is in there specifically so that you can extract the XMP data without having to parse the PDF format (or any other format the XMP metadata blob might be embedded in.

You can download the XMP specification here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html. Part 1 is the part where the explanation about XMP Packets explains how a text scanner can find the XMP packet with more accuracy.

Finally, PDF has an additional quirk that allows it to be incrementally updated. This might cause multiple XMP packets to appear in the file (where the last packet is normally the correct one). But annoyingly when the PDF is exported from applications like InDesign, images in the PDF (and other objects) might also have their own "object" XMP attached to it.

So consider where your files come from and how many strange things you might encounter and you want to provision for. But reading the XMP specification is not a bad idea for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and the link to the XMP spec, something I completely failed to find when I was originally looking at this - I'll give it a look, although I'm only using it on PDFs from one vendor and they are consistent in format.

Comment: Reading your profile, you have done quite a bit in the Adobe arena, do you have any idea how to solve my issue with regard to searching a PDX catalog in a web browser?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be very easy to do so. The last I heard (which is old information) is that the specification is actually proprietary information from a company called "Verity" which now refers to HP's web site. That probably means the trail ends there :-)